# Require code for entering column values from different users for a particular row

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I am creating a table in mysql named **result** which will have 4 fields i.e.

table **result**

```
name ,
subject1_score ,
sub2_score ,
sub3_score
```

Now what I am doing is giving seperate forms to 3 teachers for entering their respective subject scores. For example, *teacher_1* will see all roll numbers and will be required to put `subject1_score` and then submit. Similarly for other two teachers. So what code I have to use in `php` and `mysql` in order to put values in a row for particular student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure what name stand for (student or teacher) and i'm assuming that there are 3 subjects and each teacher has to submit the respective score and you want all data to be set in one row like (roll_num, name, subject 1 score, subject 2 score, subject 3 score).
if that's ture then this should work for you:

```
if (isset("name") && isset("roll_number)){

$name = $_GET["name"];
$roll_no = $_GET["roll_number"];

if (isset("subject1_score")){
$subject = "subject1_score";
$score = $_GET['subject1_score'];
}elseif(isset("subject2_score")){
$subject = "subject2_score";
$score = $_GET['subject2_score'];
}elseif(isset("subject3_score")){
$subject = "subject3_score";
$score = $_GET['subject3_score'];
}else{
$subject = "";
$score = "";
}


$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($con, dbname);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM result WHERE roll_number='$roll_no'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num == 0 && $subject != ""){
$query2 = "INSERT INTO result(roll_number, name, $subject) VALUES('$roll_no', '$name', '$score')";
mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
}elseif($num > 0 && $subject != ""){
$query2 = "UPDATE result SET $subject='$score' WHERE roll_number='$roll_no'"
}else{
echo "subject score is empty";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches, first you either fill the table with student names/roll_nos or second, you keep it blank. But please keep a field for roll numbers as they are unique and can serve you as primary keys.

In the first approach, you just have to edit the particular row for the particular roll no for whom the marks have been entered. For this you just need to run mysql's update query, like,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET subject1_score='$subject!_score' WHERE roll_no='$roll_no'");
```

and so on. In here you have to fetch the roll no and marks from the form through PHP.

In the second approach, you have to first check if the roll no is present in the database table by running a `SELECT` query and counting the no of rows by `mysql_num_rows'. If the no of rows is more than 0, then you have to update the roll_no by running the update query. If the no of rows returned are 0, you need to insert the date by running the insert query.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanx a lot bro. i ll try nd get back to you